# javascript variable scope in callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm curious how could this be written better:

```
function Klass(variable) {
    this.variable = variable;

    this.callAjax = function() {
        $.get('/url', { }, function(json) {
            console.log(variable); //! <-- shows undefined
        }, "json");
    }
}
```

so I create a local variable: _variable

```
function Klass(variable) {
    this.variable = variable;

    this.callAjax = function() {
        var _variable = this.variable;
        $.get('/url', { }, function(json) {
            console.log(_variable); //! <-- its ok
        }, "json");
    }
}
```

and its fine, but I really don't this solutions,

Does someone of you have a better code?

Comment: `$.get(...function(){...}.bind(this))`

Comment: I can't see why `console.log(variable);` should show `undefined`. `variables` should refer to the constructor argument. Do you pass `undefined` to the constructor and set `this.variable` later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's quite the way.

```
function(json){console.log(_variable);}
```

forms a closure with "_variable". 
"_variable" keeps the original value forever.

If your "variable" should be updated later, and you want the updated "variable"
You define

```
var self = this;
```

and call self.variable to get it.

In this way you'll get the updated "variable" each time the callback is executed.

The complete code:

```
function Klass(variable) {
    var self = this;
    this.variable = variable;
    this.callAjax = function() {
        $.get('/url', { }, function(json) {
            console.log(self.variable);
        }, "json");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can declare `self` in the constructor as well, since `callAjax` is a privileged method (declared in the constructor). Your approach is better since it works in prototype methods as well, though.

Comment: You're right, I wonder why the first case in the question is not working. It should be working, just the variable will not change.